# Authors in amsart

Tags: titles, amsart

Is there any way of having a nicely formatted authors section in `amsart`?

By nicely formated I mean something like here:

[image]

Comment: If all else fails, there are manual ways of obtaining what you're after.

Comment: @Werner Thank you. I am just surprised that I did not find much information about dealing with authors in amsart

Comment: I would say that the standard `amsart` styling of author information is "nice".  You are asking for an "alternative".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perhaps sub-optimal, but it reproduces the desired output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endabstract}{\@setabstract}
\newcommand{\authorfootnotes}{\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \LARGE 
  More than one Author with different Affiliations \par \bigskip

  \normalsize
  \authorfootnotes
  Author A\footnote{Author A}\textsuperscript{1}, Author B\footnote{Author B}\textsuperscript{2},
  Author C\footnote{Author C}\textsuperscript{1}, Author D\footnote{Author D}\textsuperscript{2} and
  Author E\footnote{Author E}\textsuperscript{2} \par \bigskip

  \textsuperscript{1}Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University \par
  \textsuperscript{2}Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University\par \bigskip

  \today
\end{center}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

`\@setabstract` is added to the end of the `abstract` environment to print it immediately after it is created. [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart) sets the abstract in a box first, and only prints it with a call to `\maketitle` (which we circumvent in the above MWE).

Also, the footnote mechanism is altered within the title (which is `center`ed) to print symbols via the macro `\authorfootnotes`.

Some modifications that may be required:

1. If you have other footnotes within the document, you may have to reset the footnote counter after the title. To do this, use `\setcounter{footnote}{0}`.
2. If you have figures on the first page that may end up at the top of the page, modifications to the number of top-aligned floats is required.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`amsaddr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsaddr). This is useful only in `amsart`.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate by means of a relevant example?