# amsart option titlepage puts the address on the last page

Tags: formatting, titles, amsart, affiliation

The following code produces a title page with the title, authors, and abstract, but the addresses appear at the end of the article.  Every variation I can think of produces the same problem.  Putting `\usepackage{amsaddr}` puts the addresses on the title page, but *deletes the author names*! (**edit:  amsaddr needs to be loaded before the author information to avoid the aforementioned error; see answer to question)**

I don't know what to do, short of hacking together the title manually, as in the answer to [Authors in amsart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55462/3954).

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}
\title{The title}%

\author{Author 1}
\author{Author 2}
\address{Addresses of Author 1 and 2}
\email{emails of Authors 1 and 2}

\author{Author 3}
\author{Author 4}
\address{Addresses of Author 3 and 4}
\email{emails of Authors 3 and 4}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  An abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The appears on the title page
[image]

This appears on the next page
[image]

Comment: This is the default for AMS classes.

Comment: Any idea how to force the affiliations onto the first page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `amsaddr` package does not delete the author names.  There are two ways to use it, straight it will print the address below each author name (but put the email addresses a footnote), with the `foot` option it will put the addresses in a footnote.  Here are the two outputs.

For `amsaddr` in the `foot` case you can give an optional argument to `\address`

```
\address[A1,A2]{Address of author 1 and 2}
```

which will print `(A1,A2)` before that address, if you need that labelling.  This doesn't work with the email addresses.  However, you can add the following to your preamble to get such functionality:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\email}[2][]{%
  \ifx\emails\@empty\relax\else{\g@addto@macro\emails{,\space}}\fi%
  \@ifnotempty{#1}{\g@addto@macro\emails{\textrm{(#1)}\space}}%
  \g@addto@macro\emails{#2}%
}
\makeatother
```

## Address under author

```
 \documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}
 \usepackage{amsaddr}
 Author info....
```

[image: Sample on titlepage]

## Address in foot

```
 \documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}
 \usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}
 Author info....
```

[image: Sample in foot]

## Address in foot with labels

[image: Sample with labels]

## Full code

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}

\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\email}[2][]{%
  \ifx\emails\@empty\relax\else{\g@addto@macro\emails{,\space}}\fi%
  \@ifnotempty{#1}{\g@addto@macro\emails{\textrm{(#1)}\space}}%
  \g@addto@macro\emails{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\tracingmacros=1
\title{The title}%

\author{Author 1}
\author{Author 2}
\address[A1,A2]{Addresses of Author 1 and 2}
\email[A1,A2]{emails of Authors 1 and 2}

\author{Author 3}
\author{Author 4}
\address[A3,A4]{Addresses of Author 3 and 4}
\email[A3,A4]{emails of Authors 3 and 4}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  An abstract
\end{abstract}


\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently you need to load the amsaddr package before the author info, and I hadn't done that.  This is a solution, so thanks!

Comment: Indeed. `amsaddr` redefines the macros for specifying the address and email information, so needs to be loaded first.