# Contact details on first page in amsart without overwriting headers

Tags: formatting, header-footer, amsart

By default the `amsart` class puts authors' contact details (addresses and emails) at the end of the document. The package `amsaddr` can be used to show these details on the first page, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226786/amsart-option-titlepage-puts-the-address-on-the-last-page/226826), but it seems to affect the header as well: by default, `amsart` has the names of author(s) on even pages and the title on odd pages, but once `amsaddr` is loaded, the title appears on all pages. Is there a way to prevent `amsaddr` doing this?

---

MWE to demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\address{Somewhere over the rainbow}
\email{me@wayupuhigh.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

First page.
\newpage
Second page.
\newpage
Third page.

\end{document}
```

(Note that the header on page 2 says "Title" instead of "Me". This happens regardless of whether the `foot` option is present.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `amsaddr` package does

```
\@mkboth{\@nx\shortauthors}{\@nx\shorttitle}
```

and so if you don't specify the `\shortauthors`, the first argument would be empty and `amsart` substitutes it with `\shorttitle`.

A simple solution is to use the optional argument to `\author`:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[foot]{amsaddr}

\title{Title}
\author[Me]{Me}
\address{Somewhere over the rainbow}
\email{me@wayupuhigh.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

First page.
\newpage
Second page.
\newpage
Third page.

\end{document}
```