# Separation of two authors using the amsart document class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, pdftex, article, amsart

I want to achieve a similar result to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/whats-the-correct-use-of-author-when-multiple-authors) (see answer). However, I am using the amsart document class and the result for that code is this:

[image]

The problem I believe is with the \and command that has a different behavior (or does not exist) in amsart.

I am using pdflatex and TeX Live 2013.

Comment: the entire top matter is treated differently in `amsart`, with regard to both input and formatting.  (it's not just a redefinition of `and`.)  in a tex live (full) distribution, in the area `TEXMF/doc/latex/amscls/` there is a file `amsart-template.tex`.  make a copy and fill in all the top matter elements with appropriate information, then process it and look at the output to see the style.  elements like address and email address are held out and set at the end of the article.  making changes to get the result you want is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

This may be misunderstanding your issue but amsart uses multiple `\author` commands to add each author, the relevant packages called by the document class then combine these as is set by the AMS preferences.  The instructions to authors on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart) provide a concise but relatively straightforward guide.  Inserting the following code before `\maketitle` should have the desired effect

```
\author[F1.LastName1]{FirstName1 LastName1}
\address{Address1}
\email{First1.Last1@domain.com}
\author[F2.LastName2]{FirstName2 LastName2}
\address{Address2}
\email{First2.Last2@domain.com}
```

When one then uses the `\maketitle` command all `\author` entries (and appropriate author details).  There are some discussions on customising amsart titles on here [amsart option titlepage puts the address on the last page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226786/106162) and [Authors in amsart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55462/106162) but again as barbara beaton commented, customising will not in general be a trivial task as noted by barbara beeton.

An alternative, similar documentclass to look into could be revtex (which is used for APS journals), which offers a wide range of journal styles but is no more customisable.